# How to unpack list values in DataFrame with the same amount of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to unpack DataFrame, which looks like that (sample data):
[image]

As you can see there are for example 2 users who are packed in this data frame. I want to have output with as many Data Frames as I have users in the lists. So in this example I would like to have 2 Data Frames with values like that (example for the first one in the list):
[image]

And another one of course with values from the second elements of the lists. I was trying to use explode method, but it is not working as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processing each column and select first value of tuples in indexing:

```
#if there are lists columns
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str[0])
```

Or first remove `[` and split by comma before indexing:

```
#if there are strings columns
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('[').str.split(',').str[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, the easiest solutions are always the best and sometimes it is hard to get them ;)